# making changes on remote branches

Tags: git

I have a branch on origin branch1.

How do I checkout the branch and make changes on that branch and then push the changes back to origin.

So checkout origin/branch1

make changes on that branch

then push to origin

Answer (score 2):

I think your question answers itself:

```
git checkout branch1
# make your changes
git push origin branch1
```

Comment: @KermittheFrog what does `git pull && git branch -a` output?

Comment: Arr, accidentally added remote there. Fixed. Thanks, @user1615903.